# ListQueuesSegmented vs ListQueues

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am using Azure Storage Queue Client to list all the queues that have been created. There are these two methods `client.ListQueuesSegmented` and `client.ListQueues` that are in the SDK. Both allow you to query using a prefix. `ListQueuesSegmented` uses a token which help you to query the next segment. I am trying to understand in what scenarios you would use one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListQueuesSegmented returns the results to you in chunks... to iterate over the list of all queues, you make successive calls to ListQueuesSegmented and pass in the QueueContinuationToken from the prior QueueResultSegment return value (or null if this is the first call to ListQueuesSegmented).

ListQueues will return all the queues to you with one call... but that can be very expensive if you have many queues. Prefer the segmented method unless you know you'll only return a small number of queues.

You should also consider using the async version of these methods, to avoid blocking the calling thread while you wait for results to return.

Best of luck!

Comment: "but that can be very expensive". What does expensive in this context mean? In my test code locally developmentstorage I am able to retrieve 1000 queues no issues using ListQueues. Definitely if I am doing this over production it will take time. But is it expensive as in dollar wise. Another issue is let say 50,000 queues, at that scale why would someone do listQueues or ListQueuesSegmented. I don't see the point in either of them since I will get queues using a prefix. Thanks.

Comment: Expense in this case means the possibility of large amounts of data returned from the API, if you have many queues and are not otherwise filtering the results. ListQueuesSegmented merely allows you to implement paging over the results.

As you'll be filtering the results already, you may very well not need to return results in segments.